# Dynamically adding row to datatable adds two rows

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataGridView 'DGV_MachinesExclusion' that's bound to a DataTable 'ExcludedMachines'. When manually adding a new row in the DataGridView I use the CellValueChanged event of the DataGridView to trigger the code below.

```
        private void DGV_MachinesExclusion_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow dr = ExcludedMachines.NewRow();
        dr = ((DataRowView)DGV_MachinesExclusion.Rows[0].DataBoundItem).Row;
        ExcludedMachines.Rows.Add();
        UpdateExlusionList();
    }
```

The result is that it adds two rows. One blank row and one row with the manually added data.
The method 'UpdateExclusionList()' just write the DataTable to an XML file.
I have used this way of dynamically adding rows succesfully in the past. Can anyone explain why this code adds two rows?

Thx, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
 ExcludedMachines.Rows.Add();
```

would add a blank row because you haven't specified in the 'add' function what to add to the rows - you should put

```
ExcludedMachines.Rows.Add(dr);
```

instead to populate that row.

When you're triggering the event, is it changing the cell value that triggered it (i.e. is it firing the event more than once when you expect it to only run once)? And have you double checked the 'UpdateExclusionList()' method that it definitely doesn't contain any addition row creation code by accident (left in from a test possibly?)?

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're correct that it adds a blanc row because the row isn't populated. I have already changed that but then it just adds two populated rows. The 'UpdateExclusionList()' method definately doesn't add rows because I tested the event without the code above this method. Nothing happened to the DataTable.

Comment: Also, when I put a break in the event it only gets stopped once. So I don't think the event is being triggered twice. When I leave the line: 'ExcludedMachines.Rows.Add()' out of the code then nothing gets added to the DataTable...

Comment: That would suggest the problem lies with the DataRow line. Have you tried:
`DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)DGV_MachinesExclusion.Rows[0].DataBoundItem).Row`
and then adding that direct to the table?

Comment: Actually I have, with the same results. But in checking your first suggestion, populating the Rows.Add method with 'dr' I get an ArgumentException. It says "This row already belongs to this table."

Comment: Suggests something funky is going on when the new row is created. If you comment out the line `ExcludedMachines.Rows.Add();` does it add the row to the table with the correct data with the remaining lines?

Comment: No it doesn't. I added a textbox and button now to add a row. Code looks like this when pressing the button.
            `private void Btn_AddExcludedMachine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow dr = ExcludedMachines.NewRow();
            dr[0] = Tb_AddExcludedMachine.Text;
            ExcludedMachines.Rows.Add(dr);
            UpdateExlusionList();
        }`
This works.